# Count duplicate lineups in R

Tags: r

I run a simulation and create 10,000 lineups.  I wish to tabulate the number of lineups created. For example here are 5 lineups...

```
col_1 <- c("Mary", "Jane", "Latoya", "Sandra", "Ebony", "Jada")
col_2 <- c("Jack", "Malik", "Brett", "Demetrius", "Jalen","David")
col_3 <- c("Mary", "Jane", "Latoya", "Sandra", "Ebony", "Jada")
col_4 <- c("Katie", "Emily", "Tara", "Imani", "Molly", "Claire")
col_5 <- c("Mary", "Jane", "Latoya", "Sandra", "Ebony", "Jada")
df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3,col_4,col_5)
```

The output I would like is something on the order of...

Lineup A = col_1, col_3, col5 = 3

Lineup B = col_2 = 1

Lineup C = col_5 = 1

I have knocked my head against the wall investigating the dplyr package for solution. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my solution:

```
df_t <- df %>% 
  # Transpose the dataset, make sure people are sorted alphabetically
  gather(lineup_number, person_name) %>% # Lineup/Person Level
  arrange(lineup_number, person_name) %>% # Arrange alphabetically
  group_by(lineup_number) %>% 
  mutate(person_order = paste0("person", row_number())) %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(person_order, person_name) # Row: Lineup. Column: Person

df_t %>% 
  select(starts_with("person")) %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  summarise(num_lineups = n())
```

Comment: Ryan Baxter-King

Answer (score 2):

here's a `tidyverse` only solution where we arrange all the cols, collapse, take unique values, transpose, and group to get the counts.  This approach gives the team members as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  arrange_all() %>%
  mutate_all(funs(paste0(., collapse = ","))) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(col       = colnames(df)) %>% 
  group_by(team    = V1) %>% 
  summarise(count  = n(), 
            lineup = paste(col, collapse = ","))


print(df2)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  team                                   count lineup           
  <fct>                                  <int> <chr>            
1 Ebony,Jada,Jane,Latoya,Mary,Sandra         3 col_1,col_3,col_5
2 Jalen,David,Malik,Brett,Jack,Demetrius     1 col_2            
3 Molly,Claire,Emily,Tara,Katie,Imani        1 col_4
```

Answer (score 1):

First we make sure that the levels in all columns of the data frame do match and strip off those to get numerics.

```
(d2 <- sapply(d, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels=sort(unique(unlist(d)))))))
#      col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
# [1,]     5    10     5    16     5
# [2,]     3    12     3    14     3
# [3,]     4     7     4    18     4
# [4,]     6     9     6    15     6
# [5,]     1    11     1    17     1
# [6,]     2     8     2    13     2
```

Then we could apply `toString` on columns, factorize them and split them on factor levels; we only want the `names`,

```
n <- lapply(split(m <- factor(apply(d2, 2, toString)), m), names)
```

which is actually the result, that we `rbind` together with their `length`s.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(n, function(x) cbind(toString(x), length(x))))
res
#     [,1]                  [,2]
# [1,] "col_2"               "1" 
# [2,] "col_4"               "1" 
# [3,] "col_1, col_3, col_5" "3"
```

Finally, we might want to give the matrix some meaningful `dimnames`.

```
dimnames(res) <- list(paste("Lineup", LETTERS[1:nrow(res)]), c("col", "n"))
res
#            col                   n  
# Lineup A "col_2"               "1"
# Lineup B "col_4"               "1"
# Lineup C "col_1, col_3, col_5" "3"
```

*Note:* If you have more than 26 lineups, you may want to do just `1:nrow(res)` instead of `LETTERS[1:nrow(res)]`.